# Angularjs prevent pageload at start and display value on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input Button that takes a Room ID.

```
<form>
    <div>
        Enter Room Id<input type="text" ng-model="room_id" />
        <div>         
            <a href="/api/roomInfo/{{room_id}}">Account</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then it populates following with the date from scope.

```
<div>
   <span ng-model="room.s_date" ng-init="sDate=func(room[0].s_date)">{{sDate |date: 'mediumDate'}}</span>
  </div>
```

The scope room returns an array of data from which I read element[0] to get my value. I can't run ng-repeat because I need to display this value only once.

Cotroller

```
App.controller('roomCtrl', function ($scope, roomRepository,  $location, $routeParams) {
 $scope.room = roomRepository.query({ id: $routeParams.room_id }, function (data) {
        $scope.room = data;
    });
});
```

The problems I'm having are:

```
1. When the page gets loaded, the ng-init runs as well and scope doesn't have a value  so it throws an error saying the date not defined. 

2. Second problem is I can't seem to display the date in the <span>
```

I am trying to figure out a way so ng-init doesn't run until I have entered the ID. I looked at ngCloak but it just delays for a little bit.

Please let me know how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Paste your controller. There's currently no correlation between `room_id` and `room`.

Comment: @Farrugia I added the cotroller code in the main content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things don't add up

1. Why does `roomRepository.query` both set `$scope.room` in its callback, and as its return value?
2. Where is your `ng-controller`?
3. Why do you reference `room.s_date` and `room[0].s_date` in your span?

If I'm understanding your intention, you can replace your `span` with

```
{{room[0].s_date |date: 'mediumDate'}}
```